# Pass Authorization header to Odata connector in Pipeline

Tags: azure-data-factory, odata

I have created a pipeline with below connectors.

1. Web request -> Gets the toekn and passed to next connectory ( Copy activity)
2. Copy Activity

Source: OData connector
Destination: SQL Servr

3. I need to pass token from the web request output to Copy Activity command. How can I access and pass?

I tried below approach but there is no luck.

- @concat('Bearer ', activity('GetToken').output.id_token)

I dont see an option to pass the value in the source.

[image]

Below is the dataset.

[image]

Also, I can't pass dynamic value on Odata connector.

[image]

Pipeline flow:

[image]

Comment: Can you give your source dataset configurations? and what is the `Authorization` here in the copy activity source?

Comment: It is a odata endpoint and I need to pass token

Comment: yeah, what is the `Authorization` here in the copy activity source? Is that a dataset parameter?

Comment: I understood your question. Just want to know what is `Authorization` here in that copy activity source? Is that a dataset parameter? Can you provide the picture of dataset configurations for better understanding?

Comment: There is no parameter. I need to read GetToken activity output and pass to Odata connector in CopyActivity pipeline. adding more images

Answer (score 0):

In General, to give values from previous activity to current activity linked service, we need to use linked service parameters in the UI.

But in this case, as the dynamic content is not supported in linked service UI, you need to update the linked service JSON.

In ADF, Go to **Manage** -> **Linked services** -> **OData** linked service -> Click on `{}` icon.

Edit the JSON like below.

```
{
    "name": "OData1",
    "properties": {
        "parameters": {
            "AuthToken": {
                "type": "string"
            }
        },
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "OData",
        "typeProperties": {
            "url": "<your_URL>",
            "authenticationType": "Anonymous",
            "authHeaders": {
                "Authorization": {
                    "type": "Expression",
                    "value": "@{linkedService().AuthToken}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Click on **Apply**.

[image]

Now, linked service parameter will ask the required dynamic content. You can directly give the expression `@concat('Bearer ', activity('GetToken').output.id_token)` here or you can give it at the pipeline level by using dataset parameters for this.

Create a dataset parameter and give it to the linked service parameter.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Go through the [Similar Ask](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/588671/how-to-update-the-odata-linked-service-with-access) by @[MartinJaffer-MSFT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/users/na/?userid=54707856-1a8e-4122-9554-0a0ebb91d154) to know more about this.

Comment: How does the toekn is passed to LinkedService parameter? How to access linked service parameter in source? I have been trying but that is not successful.

Comment: You need to edit the linked service JSON like above. There, edit the JSON like highlighted part to create linked service parameter and to assign that parameter to the authorization header. Later, in the dataset, it will show the linked service parameter and there provide your dynamic content.